# SPI loaded but MOSI as input

Tags: pi-2, spi

I wrote a script to display data on a led matrix, controlled by a few GPIO for line selection and SPI to feed data for this line. This was working perfectly 2 days ago, I let the script display random data for a few hours then stopped the rpi via ssh.

Today it is not working anymore and I'm surprised by the ouput of `gpioinfo`:

```
gpiochip0 - 54 lines:

...
    line   7:   "SPI_CE1_N"         output active-low consumer="spi0 CS1"
    line   8:   "SPI_CE0_N"         output active-low consumer="spi0 CS0"
    line   9:   "SPI_MISO"          input
    line  10:   "SPI_MOSI"          input
    line  11:   "SPI_SCLK"          input
...
```

**Shouldn't MOSI and SCLK be output, consumed by the same than CE1/CE0 ports ?**

SPI modules are loaded (with `spidev` `Used by` column switching to `2` when I start my script)

```
# lsmod | grep spi
spidev                 20480  0
spi_bcm2835            20480  0
```

The SPI devices are present and udev correctly set up the groups

```
# ls -l /dev/spidev0.*
crw-rw---- 1 root spi 153, 0 Apr 17 08:43 /dev/spidev0.0
crw-rw---- 1 root spi 153, 1 Apr 17 08:43 /dev/spidev0.1

# cat /etc/udev/rules.d/localr.rules 
SUBSYSTEM=="gpio", KERNEL=="gpiochip*", GROUP="gpio", MODE="0660"
KERNEL=="spidev*", GROUP="spi", MODE="0660"

# grep spi /boot/config.txt 
dtparam=spi=on
```

Display part of my code, where `img` is a basic 16x16 bit array.
GPIO code is for line selection and is working well

```py
spi_bus=0
spi_device=0

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(spi_bus, spi_device)

...

    with libgpiod.Chip(gpio_chip_path) as chip:
        lines_settings = {line: libgpiod.LineSettings(direction=Direction.OUTPUT, output_value=Value(0))
                          for line in gpio_lines}
        linebulk = chip.request_lines(lines_settings, consumer="ledmatrix")
        while True:
            for c in range(0, 16):
                values = {
                        21: Value(((c<<0)&0b1000) != 0),
                        20: Value(((c<<1)&0b1000) != 0),
                        16: Value(((c<<2)&0b1000) != 0),
                        12: Value(((c<<3)&0b1000) != 0),
                        5: Value(1)
                        }
                linebulk.set_values(values)
                spi.xfer(img[c][:])
                #img[c][randint(0, 15)] = randint(0, 1)
                values = { 5: Value(0) }
                linebulk.set_values(values)
                sleep(0.0001)
```

How could I debug this?

Comment: What does gpioinfo report after boot (before you run your script).

Comment: Same thing. I tried to unplug all (pins, usb …), same result …

Answer (score 1):

This may be a change to the way the driver works.

The chip select GPIO are driven active low by default.  The other SPI GPIO are left as inputs.

During a SPI transaction MOSI and SCLK are driven as outputs.

I checked by looking at the line levels when writing something to /dev/spidev0.0.

`echo abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv >/dev/spidev0.0`

During the transaction CE0 was driven low and MOSI and SCLK were seen to toggle.

Comment: thank for testing it ! Did `gpioinfo` reported something ? i don't have test hardware except a basic multimeter, but gpioinfo doesnt give me result neither with `echo`, neither with my code running

Comment: You won't see it on `gpioinfo` unless you are very lucky.  I used piscope.  http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html  You can run it in a window as the same time as your script.  If you want to see individual bits change the SPI speed to 50k bits per second or so.

Comment: I still did had time to test with piscope but I will. Thank for the hint !